# Function not called in conditional statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have a function that generates a table of contents. It works perfectly. However it also works when the page is in Edit Mode and causes a LOT of havoc.

For that, I found the solution in the second part of the code below. The code seems to work well as evidenced by the outputs in the console log, corresponding to the site being ("true") or not being ("false") in the Edit Mode. However when the site is NOT in the Edit Mode, I would expect it to call the *GenerateTOC* function, but it does not.

I have very limited understanding of javascript, so I am kind of lost here, particularly considering I seem to be able to call other functions. Normally I was calling it by

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('GenerateTOC');
```

but this I guess is not applicable anymore...

```
<div id="toc"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function GenerateTOC() {
  //...
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){  
  var InEditMode = SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.isInEditMode();  
  if(InEditMode){  
    console.log(InEditMode);
    //do nothing because site is in edit mode
  }else
  {
    console.log(InEditMode);
    GenerateTOC;
  }  
}, 'SP.Ribbon.js');
```

Comment: OMG, I feel like a retard... should call it by _GenerateTOC();_. Please advise - should I delete this question or should it be closed as a shameful reminder for posterity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is an error in your code.

You should call your function like given below:

```
GenerateTOC();
```

Instead of:

```
GenerateTOC;
```

Also, I would recommend you to check the execution of your code by adding breakpoints using developer tools of browser whenever such error occurs.

Comment: Shameful reminder for posterity it is.